# Same Origin Policy Rules For Different Possible Request types and Scenarios

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, same-origin-policy

I am trying to understand the Same Origin Policy. (The following assumes only cross-origin requests.)
From what I have understood so far, for certain requests, it allows only writes and although the request goes through, the response is not readable such as a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest/AJAX GET Request (Having Safe/Allowed Headers). In some cases, both the request passes through and the response is readable such as in cross-origin iframe requests. Whereas in other cases, a preflight check is made and if it succeeds, the request goes through and the response is readable such as a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest/AJAX DELETE request.

In order to better understand this, I have made a table with the possible types of requests and I wanted to know what happens in each of these scenarios and if what I have understood is correct. (As mentioned earlier, assume all the below requests to be cross-origin.)

[image]

Comment: This is more suitable for a wiki than a Q&A site, which is why I don't think you got any answers. That said, I believe your table is accurate except for iframes. You can't read the response of a cross-origin iframe.

Comment: Alright.Thanks. If cross-origin iframes cannot read the response, then how is it that, they load a cross-origin web page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If my page at `A.com` has an `iframe` with a `src` pointing to `B.com`, that iframe will load just fine but my scripts (loaded from `A.com`) won't be able to read the contents of the iframe. It's the same situation as an XHR `GET`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting): "Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the same-origin policy, and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain."

Comment: Ohh. So not being able to read the response in any of the above cases, basically means that scripts (from the origin that makes the cross-origin call) cannot programmatically access the response data although the browser can display it to the user?

Comment: That's right. The purpose of the Same-Origin Policy is to prevent third-party sites from accessing information, not browser users themselves. And now that I think about it, the same is true for the `<img>` tag. (The browser will display it, but won't let your script access the image data.) So move those down to the row below.